# Telerik Silverlight GridView ItemSource Error

Tags: xml, silverlight, gridview, telerik

So Ive got this application that Im working on that has a Telerik Silverlight gridview. I get dynamic XMl from a web service, create a dynamic object(this is SL 3 FYI, so no system.Dynamic or Expandos) and then build a list of the objects and return it as a System.Collections.IEnumerable. From there I set the gridView ItemsSource to the aforementioned list I just got. The problem Im having is that in this list, it has all of the columns, cells, and headers correctly, with all of the correct information, but on the gridview, any columns that contain a / character, the cell data does not get displayed. Anyone know why this might be happening and how I can get around it?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I couldn't reproduce your problem.

From what I understand of your question, the correct data is making its way into your Silverlight application via the web service, but the RadGridView is mangling any of your data that contains a `/` character.  If this is the case, then something like the following ought to reproduce the problem:

XAML (in MainWindow.xaml)

```
    <telerik:RadGridView x:Name="grid" />
```

C# (constructor in MainWindow.xaml.cs):

```c#
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        grid.ItemsSource = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>()
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("3/252/21", "1845/5649"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("19//7/36/9", "14/1/469/9"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("0/49/8/49", "0/1/00/2306")
        };
    }
```

However, this behaves correctly for me (SL4, Telerik DLLs version 2011.3.1116.1040).

Without seeing your code we can only really guess at possible answers to your question.  If the Telerik RadGridView really is mangling your data, could you at least show us the relevant parts of your code, or better yet, put together an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: I posted this on the Telerik forums and it seems as if this is a problem with the controls, because any special XMl encoded characters like a space, /, \, among others, has caused problems. Plus it would be too long, and hard for me to make a small app right now that doesnt expose data and make it look overly complicated(because of our dynamic object class/process).